# Nuxt and Vue Apollo. How to handle errors inside Smart Query with redirection to 404/400/500 error page? Can we catch such errors?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, apollo-client, vue-apollo

With regular HTTP request, we may create redirection with asyncData({error}){...}

What should we use for redirecting to 400 page using Smart Query?

With Vue Apollo, I am trying to use

```js
    apollo: {
        queryName: {
            prefetch: true,
            query: wrongQuery,
    
            error(errorData) {
                this.$nuxt.error({
                    statusCode: 500,
                    message: 'Error message',
                });
            },
        },
    };
```

In case if we reload the page, redirection doesn't work. We still got an error becouse server side rendering:

[image]

With global error handler like:

```js
    // /plugins/apollo-error-handler.js
    export default ({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward }, nuxtContext) => {
        console.log(networkError)
        nuxtContext.error({
          statusCode: 404,
          message: 'Error message',
        });
    };
```

Only errors logging works. Redirection doesn't work at all.

Do we have any way to handle errors inside smart queries with redirection to 400 page for example?

Can we catch such errors in smart query? Like try...catch... in asyncData() to prevent app crash.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module/issues/315)!

```
export default function ({ redirect }) {
  const link = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors) {
    graphQLErrors.map(({ message }) => {
      if (`${message}` === 'Unauthenticated.') {
        redirect('/login')
        // Do Something
        localStorage.setItem('logged', false)
      }
    })
  }
  if (networkError) {
    console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`)
  }
})
  return {
    defaultHttpLink: false,
    link: ApolloLink.from([link, createHttpLink({
      credentials: 'include',
      uri: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql',
      fetch: (uri, options) => {
        options.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')
        return fetch(uri, options)
      }
    })]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  }
}`
```

Hopefully this answer helpful for you! 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The smart query like this is pretty limited and so, I prefer to handle it in my Vuex store. Not sure if it's the best practice but it works great for me right now.

```js
async niceFancyVuexAction({ dispatch }, { fancyInput }) {
  try {
    const { errors, data } = await this.app.apolloProvider.defaultClient.mutate({
      mutation: yourGraphqlMutationHere,
      errorPolicy: 'all',
      variables: {
        input: fancyInput,
      },
    })

    if (errors) {
      return dispatch('handleErrors', 'we got some errors')
    }

    dispatch('anotherNiceFancyVuexAction', data.Address.createForCompany)
    
    console.log('success !')
  } catch (error) {
    // here, you could catch the error and maybe make a redirect
    dispatch('handleErrors', 'the call was not successfull')
  }
},
```

Otherwise, yeah using the `onError` link is also a good idea if you feel configuring it: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do you handle the loading state? With smart query we may use this.$apollo.loading to show spinner. What should we use in case of your approach?

Comment: Thanks for the bounty ! In this case, I do call my vuex action into the `fetch()` nuxt hook, and use `$fetchState.pending` helper: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-fetch/ But there is maybe also a `loading` variable that can be destructured from the graphql call, did not checked this one.